# Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined at render - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want my `Points-Sphere` to be animated (rotating), however I get this message when adding `particles.rotation` to the render:

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rh3t0x3v/

```
function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera, particles);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  //particles.rotation.y += 0.004;

}
```

I came across older questions, so it may be that it's initialized asynchronously or that I need to wait until the `Points-Sphere` is fully loaded before calling the animation.. but I don't know how to.

Comment: You are redeclaring `particles`. Do `particles = ...` instead of `var particles = ...`

Comment: ahh - ok but i'm getting this: "Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined".

Comment: ok fixed it! thank you very very much